# Display generic columns and rows based on data Size

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have a little problem. I want to display 4 columns per row in my screen, the problem is that the data are generated from loop.

Here is my code

**hello.xhtml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <head>
    <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{helloWorld.init()}"></h:inputHidden>
        #{helloWorld.getMessage()}
        <ui:repeat var="user" value="#{helloWorld.users}">
                <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 10%; margin-top: 1%;">
                    <p>#{user.address}</p>
                </div>
        </ui:repeat>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: The actual view]

I whish i can display them 4 by 4 per every row as more as data size increases.

PS : I'm not allowed to use bootstrap.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try add in your CSS the follow line:

```
float: left;
```

I hope to have helped in some way

Comment: Simply adding float will never give you columns

Comment: @JasperdeVries is correct... Add that in combination with a selector that only applies this every n-th div. And you can put these in media queries as well so depending on the screen real-estate, 4, 6 or e.g. 10  on a row are displayed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your `<ui:repeat>` with an `<h:panelGrid>` and specify the number of columns using the `columns` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use a h:panelGrid where you can define the columns like ... something like this

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5" >
        <ui:repeat var="user" value="#{helloWorld.users}">
                <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 10%; margin-top: 1%;">
                        <p>#{user.address}</p>
                </div>
        </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

I have to say I didn't try this code, so I don't know if it worked but hope it help you!